# JOIN tables but with a second id

Tags: mysql, left-join

it is hard to explain but I will try.

I have a table "users" a table "urls" and a table "titles" and want to have a list of all users from a category with the help of an "categories_users" table with one query.

My Query with urls **works** and looks like this:

```
SELECT categories_users.users_uid, users.firstname, urls.name
FROM categories_users
LEFT JOIN users ON categories_users.users_uid = users.uid
LEFT JOIN urls ON categories_users.users_uid = urls.target_uid
WHERE
    ...
```

But now I need the title of a person and try to add another JOIN statement, but unfortunately my query stops without an error.

I tried and **doesn't work**:

```
SELECT categories_users.users_uid, users.firstname, urls.name, users.titles_uid
FROM categories_users
LEFT JOIN users ON categories_users.users_uid = users.uid
LEFT JOIN urls ON categories_users.users_uid = urls.target_uid
LEFT JOIN titles ON users.titles_uid = uid.titles
WHERE
 ...
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks and greetings
Bazi

Comment: `ON users.titles_uid = uid.titles` should probably be `ON users.titles_uid = titles.uid`

Comment: Oh yes it works! Thank you! I'm so blind!